# Cannot remove default top margin of chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I am unable to remove default top margin after many attempts. Below is my html and css code. Please suggest where I am lacking?

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Sample</title>   
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="maincontainer">
            <div id="header">   
                <h1>Sample</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="contents">
        Body of page
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS File**

```
html, body
{
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    background:#fff;
    font-family:Times New Roman;
    font-size: 16px;
    width:1024px;   
}

#maincontainer
{
    margin:0;
    padding:5px;
}

#header 
{   
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100px;
    background:#8A0808;
    text-align:left;
}

h1
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: You mean something like this? Your `#maincontainer` has `5px` padding. Use `padding-left` and `padding-right` instead - http://jsfiddle.net/CTLah/

Comment: #maincontainer has padding simply remove that in css

Comment: JunM and Pravin - Thanks for sorting it out within a minute :) I wish I could upvote you 5 times on SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`padding: 5px;` on the #maincontainer might be your issue.  There's going to be 5px of white surrounding anything inside of the #maincontainer div.